# plotyy change colors

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am using plotyy function in MATLAB. It is effectively 2 plots, each with 5  'lines'. I want the 5 lines to match in colors, but am not managing. I have tried various methods from set handle to colororder - see below.

The two variables, pk3... are vectors of 5 columns each.

```
[ax,h1,h2]= plotyy(2007:2050,pk3uco25,2007:2050,pk3ux45)
```

I have used the lines below to control the other properties, ...

```
set(h1,'linestyle', 'd','marker','*', 'markersize', 5) %variable 1
set(h2,'linestyle', '-', 'linewidth', 1.5)             %variable 2
```

What I would like is that the first 5 lines, match the color of the second 5 lines. I have tried  various things such as:

- setting a colororder that repeats itself such that `mycolororder{1:5,:} == mycolororder{6:10,:}`

  `set(gca,'colororder',mycolororder); %`
- using a matrix of values

`cols(1:5,1)={'color'};`

```
cols(:,2)=get(h1,'color');
set(h2,cols{1:5,1},cols{1:5,2});
```

... and a few other things but no luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to set `h2` colors to be the same as `h1` colors use this line:

```
set(h2, {'Color'}, get(h1,'Color'));
```

for example:

```
x=1:5;
y1=meshgrid(10:10:50,1:5);
y2=y1+1;
[ax,h1,h2]= plotyy(x,y1,x,y2);
set(h2, {'Color'},get(h1,'Color'));
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks so much. I had tried some set.. get  lines earlier and for some reason didn't get it to work. Simple solution,  - it was Friday! Many thanks again.